# bpftool: unable to understand lpm_trie keys

Tags: networking, kernel, c

I am entering the following commands:

```
$ sudo bpftool map create /sys/fs/bpf/routes type lpm_trie key 6\
 value 1 entries 256 name routes flags 1

$ sudo bpftool map update id 194 key 8 0 0 0 0 10 value 1
$ sudo bpftool map update id 194 key 16 0 0 0 107 10 value 3
$ sudo bpftool map update id 194 key 24 0 0 0 107 10 value 3
Error: update failed: Invalid argument
$
```

I understood the following from self experimentation:

> .. key # # _ _ _ _ value ..

- The `#` are the prefix
- The `_` can be anything from 0-255

What I am not able to understand is, that why a prefix of `24` **doesn't work**?

> PS: I **couldn't find any documentation**, on what is the `key structure` to be used while updating an `lpm_trie` in `bpf maps`

I could find one web page, sharing the man pages of `bpftool`:

- https://www.mankier.com/8/bpftool-map

Another iteration of the issue:
[image: Issue]

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but seeing as its the top google result to this and I ran into it as well, I'll give an answer.

For [lpm_trie](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/map_lpm_trie.html#bpf-map-type-lpm-trie) types, the keys are stored as `prefixlen,data` as the question indicates, but the `prefixlen` is a 32 bit value. Seeing as the map was created with `key 6`, 4 of these bytes used by the prefix leaving 2 bytes for the data resulting in a maximum prefix length of 16.

Comment: Thanks @J C for the answer